# Can C# .NET be used for hard real-time?

Tags: c#, .net, real-time

Given that the familiar form of .NET is run on Windows, which is not a real-time O/S, and MONO runs on Linux (standard kernel is also not a real-time O/S).

Given also, that any memory allocation scheme offering garbage collection (as in "managed" .NET), and indeed any heap memory scheme will introduce non-deterministic, potentially non-trivial delays into an application's execution behavior.

Is there any combination of alternate host O/S and coding paradigm in which one can leverage all of the power and conveniences of C# .NET while implementing a solution which can execute designated portions of code within tightly specified time constraints? e.g. start a C# method every 10ms to a tolerance of less than 1ms, with completion time determined only by the work performed in the method itself?

Obviously, the application would have to be carefully written; time-critical code would have to avoid memory allocations; the application would have to have completed all its memory allocation etc. work and have no other threads active once the hard real-time loop is started. Also, the host O/S would have to support real-time scheduling.

Is this possible within the .NET / MONO framework, or is it precluded by the design of the .NET runtime, framework, and O/Ss on which it (or compatible equivalent) is supported?

For example: is it possible to do reliable fine-grained (~1ms) machine control purely in C# with something like [NETduino](http://netduino.com/), or do they have limits or require alternate strategies for such applications?

Comment: You will have to select your operating system first.  What's going to be left as suitable programming tools is going to be an awfully small list and will not include languages with a garbage collector.  The normal solution is to offload tasks that require hard real-time response off to micro-controllers.  A motor controller or a PLC are boilerplate examples.

Answer (score 10):

Short Answer: No.

Longer answer: The closest you can get is running the [.net Micro Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework) directly on Hardware, but the TinyCLR still doesn't give you deterministic timings. Microsoft has [Windows CE/Windows Embedded Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_CE) as their real time offering, but even that is only real time for slower tasks (I believe somewhere in the range of 50 microseconds or more - not sure if that qualifies for Hard Real Time)

I do not know if it were technically possible to create a real-time c# implementation, but no one has done one and even [.net native](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dotnetnative.aspx) isn't made for that.

Answer (score 0):

Can C# be used for hard real-time? Yes

When we talk about real-time it's most often (if not always) about robotics and IoT. And for that we almost always go with one of these options (forget Windows CE and Windows 10 IoT):

- Microcontrollers (example: Arduino, RPi Pico, NodeMCU)
- Linux based SBCs (example: Raspberry Pi, BeagleBone, Rock Pi)

Microcontrollers are by nature real-time. Basically the device will just run a loop forever (there are interrupts and multi-threading on some chips though). Top languages in this category are C/C++ and MicroPython. But C# can also be used:

- [Wilderness Labs](https://www.wildernesslabs.co/) (Netduino and Meadow F7)
- [.NET nanoframefork](https://www.nanoframework.net/) (several boards)

The second option (Linux based SBCs) is a bit more tricky. The OS has complete control over the hardware and it has a scheduler. That way many processes can be run on just one CPU. The OS itself has a lot of housekeeping as well.

Linux has a set of [scheduling APIs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html) that can be used to tell the OS that we want you to favor our process over others. And the OS will do its best to comply but no guarantees. This is usually called soft real-time. In .NET you can use the [Process.PriorityClass](http://Process.PriorityClass) to change your process's nice value. Depending on how busy the OS is and the amount of resources available (CPUs and memory) you might get satisfying results.

Other than that, Linux also provides [hard real-time capabilities](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) with the PREEMT_RT patch, and there is also a feature that [you can isolate a CPU core for your selected processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/658780/393910). But to my knowledge .NET does not have any API to use these capabilities (P/Invoke may work).