# C# Hard Real Time Thread in RT Linux?

Tags: c#, real-time

1. My understanding is that in Linux in order to run a truly Hard real-time application it needs to be compiled as a Linux kernel module and called directly by the kernel. Is that correct? If so does any have any good reading material on the subject? (something that is easy for a non C developer to understand) If not how are they interfaced with the OS to provide deterministic timing?
2. Is it possible to compile a C# program ahead-of-time with say Mono or .Net Native and have a run as a hard real-time application? The Code would, of course, have to be written so that it is fast and completes in the allotted time so that it does not get preempted. (if I understand how RT works). The idea being that there would be a Hard Real-Time main thread (with unsafe memory), that interfaced via shared memory with one or more Managed C# Thread nonrealtime threads.
3. If running C# code as Hard Real-time is not an option, would running C code as HRT be an option and then sharing memory with a .net Application?

I found this but it is 4 years old and there was only one answer and I wanted to know if anyone had anymore incite, since then
[Can C# .NET be used for hard real-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702690/can-c-sharp-net-be-used-for-hard-real-time)

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/761

Comment: "If running C# code as Hard Real-time is not an option, would running C code as HRT be an option and then sharing memory with a .net Application?" - how is sharing-memory an improvement? How do you plan to share memory between a C and  C# program?

Comment: Hard-real time isnt' about JIT compiling, it's about how threads and tasks are handled *after* that step and the program starts working. Hard real time isn't about compiling to kernel either. It means that the jobs scheduled have to complete within specific constraints or the system will fail catastrophically. A real time scheduler should be able to reject tasks that would exceed those constraints. Overall performance could be slow as long as the system was guaranteed to work within the boundaries. You can't guarantee that even with a kernel module

Comment: Having managed code interact with a kernel is challenging enough without throwing in the requirement that things are hard real time. Nobody has yet undertaken the work to make either thing work smoothly in C# (or more accurately .NET in general). It's sufficiently challenging that you'd need a bunch of people with the motivation to make it work. At present .NET Core has enough challenges just getting to parity with .NET Full across platforms, and this isn't really what people are focusing on. It can be done, sure (RT Java would be a good inspiration), but it's "decidedly nontrivial".

Comment: More often than not, when people talk about real time they mean soft real time on a machine fast enough it won't encounter hard failures or get interrupted. Moving code to the kernel makes it easier to avoid hard failures but doesn't make the system hard real time