# How do we fetch real time messages from RabbitMQ queue without having any delay in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I have written code to fetch messages from `RabbitMQ` queue and executing that program every 5 minutes by adding in task scheduler.

But, this is not realtime processing. It has delay of 5 min.

I want to make it process in realtime. As on someone add message in `RabbitMQ` Queue .NET program should immediately pick it for further processing.

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: _"...i want to make it process in realtime..."_ - BTW, _[What does “Windows is `not a real-time operating system`” mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/406819/what-does-windows-is-not-a-real-time-operating-system-mean)_ and _[Can `C# .NET` be used for `hard real-time`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702690/can-c-sharp-net-be-used-for-hard-real-time)_

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are not talking about true realtime but getting the message as quickly as possible.

This is done by using **EventingBasicConsumer** in RabbitMQ

```
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(model);
consumer.Received += (ch, ea) =>
    {
       try
       {
            var body = ea.Body;
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    };
channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);
```

Comment: yes getting the message as quickly as possible. where we need to add this code?

Comment: Just put this under where you are setting up your communication with RabbitMQ